# Google Drive / List files in folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I have little question. Is there any way (I read API, but maybe...) how to list files in folder using only `Google Drive API`? I mean without scopes Documents List API.

If I send request GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files then I get all files and folders in my `Google Drive`, but I want to show only files which is inside specific folder.

My english is bad, but I hope you understand me.

If not any way to do this, then I must use Documents List API.
Thanks for answers

PS: I make app in C++/QT for MeeGo and Symbian OS mobile systems

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I must use Search string parameters with =q

Comment: I have a great sample with using Google Drive API, use it :)
http://ilyatereschuk.blogspot.com/2013/12/extraordinary-backup-solution-google.html